# Can I apply a function through all(dict.values())?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a dict of tkinter entries and corresponding StringVar that I would like to check for having Truthy/Falsy values. I know I can write my own version off all() that could iterate through the StringVar and use .get() to access the values:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root=Tk()
>>> row={'new':{}, 'old':{}}
>>> row['new']['data']=StringVar(value='something')
>>> row['new']['non_data']=StringVar(value='')
>>>
>>> def my_all(StringVarIter):
...   for element in StringVarIter:
...     if not element.get():
...       return False
...   return True
... 
>>> my_all(row['new'].values())
False
>>> row['new']['non_data']=StringVar(value='something else')
>>> my_all(row['new'].values())
True
```

Is there a cleaner, more pythonic way using just built-ins and tkinter functions? I was thinking along these lines, also tried filter(function, iterable)

```
>>> map(StringVar.get(),row['new'].values())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

But that doesn't even get me the iterable needed for all()

Comment: The first argument to map needs to be a function that takes each of the values as a single argument, e.g. `map(lambda sv: sv.get(), row['new'].values())`

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe that works. please make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were actually really close with `map(StringVar.get(), row['new'].values())`; the error is because you're calling the method on the class without providing an instance. The first argument to `map` should be a callable that takes each of the items from the iterable second argument in turn as a single parameter.

So you can actually reference the method, rather than trying to call it, and get the instances passed in turn:

```
map(StringVar.get, row['new'].values())
               # ^ note no parentheses, we're not calling the method
```

or make your own single-argument callable (you often see `lambda`s used for this):

```
map(lambda sv: sv.get(), row['new'].values())
                   # ^ this time we're calling it inside the lambda
```